# drop auto-increment fields

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, built-in

1. If solution to the problem in title is possible, please guide. I have not found it anywhere.
2. If it is possible (to drop auto-increment field without naming it at table, level please guide.
3. I can read it from `extra` field of `information_schema.columns` and have its name, then it would easy to drop that column from a specific table. But i am seeking for a better solution.
4. Is there any better/quick solution than my point#3

Question (If it is not already clear :)

Is there any query/function to drop all auto-increment columns from database? or at least is there a way to drop an auto-increment column from specific table without knowing the name of that column?

I am thinking this because there can be only 0 or 1 auto-increment column in a table, so mysql might have some built-in extended function to deal with that type of field

Comment: Almost certainly not; there isn't sufficient demand for such specialized code to make it worth people's while to implement it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler any comments about point.4? Same as above?

Comment: Information schema plus a scripting language to generate the SQL to be executed sounds about right to me.  You might even be able to do it all in the database with suitable stored procedures.  There'll be no solution provided; you'll have to build your own from the tool kits that are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such builtin function. Your point #3 is a good option to do this in MySQL. you can also parse `desc mytable` output.

Answer (score 0):

While there's no built-in mechanism to do this, you could write a script that reads `information_schema` and generates all the necessary `alter table` commands.